# load the css and js

Tags: javascript, css, tomcat, load

I'm new to the javascript and CSS. Now i meet some problems about loading CSS and js file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
<link rel="sytlesheet" type="text/css" href="css/sunny/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css">
```

I use these two lines to load the CSS files in a specific page. The other pages just load the styles.css file. However, when i go to this page, the second one never been loaded.

The other problem is the js file.
I use eclipse to develop the website. After update the js file, i restart the server and redeploy the program. But the firefox still load the old js file. Why did it happen?
I use the tomcat currently.

Comment: may simply be a caching issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're having a combination of caching issues and spelling problems. :) The second  tag has 'stylesheet' misspelled. As far as the old .js file being loaded, your browser is probably caching the file and loading the old version. Try using ctrl-f5 to refresh and see if that fixes the caching issue.

Comment: Thank you very much. That is the problem. I am so careless.